# Varieties with finitely cocomplete category of finite algebras

Tags: universal-algebra

> For which varieties $\mathbf{V}$ (in the sense of universal algebra) do the finite algebras in $\mathbf{V}$ form a finitely cocomplete category, or more strongly, are closed under finite colimits in $\mathbf{V}$?

Some examples:

- Sets
- (Left or right) $M$-sets where $M$ is any monoid
- Commutative (or abelian) semigroups
- Commutative (or abelian) monoids
- Abelian groups
- (Left or right) $R$-(semi)modules where $R$ is any ring (or rig)
- Boolean algebras

Some non-examples:

- Semigroups, monoids, groups, or rings (not necessarily commutative)
- Commutative rings (although the tensor product (coproduct) of two finite commutative rings is finite, the initial ring $\mathbf{Z}$ is infinite)

Comment: An example which satisfies the weak condition but not the strong condition: $k$-algebras for any infinite field $k$.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? Just asking "which $X$s are $Y$s?" is too simplistic.